# I want to create a folder view like Google Drive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a folder view like Google Drive using Javascript. My idea is to store all files in a folder on AWS S3, and save the info of the file to the database. I wanna display files as architecture in DB instead of architecture in S3. Is there any library to do this action?